# Google finding non existant URLs on my site and 301 redirects failing

Tags: google-search-console, htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect, soft-404

I have been checking webmaster tools and found that Google has picked up some soft 404s.

The weird thing is there are no such pages on my site and I dont know how Google has come up with these URLs.

There are over a dozen in total and here is a few examples:

```
www.mywebsite.com/products/manufacturers.php?&l=a
www.mywebsite.com/products/manufacturers.php?&l=b
www.mywebsite.com/products/manufacturers.php?&l=c
```

They basically just have a different variable at the end.

So I have tried doing a 301 redirect to our home page like so:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/products/manufacturers.php?&l=(.*)$ /
```

But it doesn't work it just send me to the custom error page because obviously the page its looking for doesn't exist.

I also tried a rewriteRule instead of a 301 redirect but that didn't work either.

Does anybody have any idea how I can make the redirect work so I can remove these from webmaster tools?

Comment: You could be getting a "**soft** 404" if your "custom error page" is not returning a 404 HTTP status code. If a page doesn't exist on your site then the correct response is a 404 - you should not be trying to redirect this to your home page!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is some mistakes in your regex.
Have you tried like bellow :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^products/manufacturers\.php?&l=(.*)$ /
```

**EDIT:** Is `products/manufacturers\.php` a real page of your site ? 
Otherwise you could use

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^products/manufacturers\.php(.*)$ / [L,R=301]
```

Tell me if it works

Comment: I'm not an expert on Regex but I tried your answer and had no luck. The result is the same. I thought the only regex in my original redirect line was (.*). It really is very strange because I see nothing wrong with my redirect and I'm lost as to how Google has these URLs in the first place

Comment: I think the query string in your regex is the problem but i'm not sure. I've edit my answer above, take a look and keep me posted.

Comment: No these were not real pages. I had a products.php page and a manufacturers.php page but not products/manufacturers.php. Anyway I have tried that rewriteRule under your edit and it works. Thank you for that I have been stuck on this for hours. :)

Comment: A bit of an aside, but... you can't match the query string in the URL using mod_alias `RedirectMatch` or mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` alone (which is why the redirect was initially failing). You need to use `RewriteCond`. (Although it seems you don't need to match the query string anyway, just the path part of the URL is sufficient.) Incidentally, `^products/manufacturers\.php(.*)$` would be the same as `^products/manufacturers\.php` (the `(.*)$` at the end is unnecessary). However, it is a bad idea to redirect a URL that should be returning a 404 - the URL has never actually existed.